# spring-boot hibernate transaction manager not rolling back transaction even on runtime exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on a spring-boot hibernate JPA personal project book-store. I'm facing a problem that the methods annotated with @Transactional annotation not rolling back transactions even with runtime exceptions. I'm using spring-boot version 1.5.1, hibernate version 5, java version 11 & DB is MySQL. I'm generating run time exception by inserting the book with the same title in books table. In BookServiceImpl's addBook method the store-entry should ideally rollback from the store table when adding the book to books table fails, but, it is currently not happening.

Below is bean config file code:

```
package com.freetests4u;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate5.Hibernate5Module;
import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class) == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("factory is not a hibernate factory");
        }
        return entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public Module datatypeHibernateModule() {
      return new Hibernate5Module();
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
          = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory());
        return transactionManager;
    }
    
//  @Bean
//  public DataSource dataSource() {
//      return new MysqlDataSource(); // (1)
//  }
//
//  @Bean
//  public PlatformTransactionManager txManager() {
//      return new HibernateTransactionManager(); // (2)
//  }
    
}
```

Below is BooK model file code

```
package com.freetests4u.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="books")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;
    
    @Column(name="writer")
    private String writer;

    @Column(name="language")
    private String language;
    
    @Column(name="category")
    private String category;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getWriter() {
        return writer;
    }

    public void setWriter(String writer) {
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
    
    

}
```

Below is store Model code

```
package com.freetests4u.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="store")
public class Store {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    int id;
    
    @Column(name="bookid")
    int bookId;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="bookid", referencedColumnName="id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    Book book;
    
    @Column(name="bookcount")
    int bookCount;
    
    @Column(name="isdeleted")
    boolean isDeleted;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getBookId() {
        return bookId;
    }

    public void setBookId(int bookId) {
        this.bookId = bookId;
    }

    public Book getBook() {
        return book;
    }

    public void setBook(Book book) {
        this.book = book;
    }

    public int getBookCount() {
        return bookCount;
    }

    public void setBookCount(int bookCount) {
        this.bookCount = bookCount;
    }

    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean isDeleted) {
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }


    
}
```

Below is BookDaoImpl code

```
package com.freetests4u.dao.impl;

import java.util.List;


import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Order;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.NoTransactionException;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.freetests4u.dao.BookDao;
import com.freetests4u.model.Book;


@Component
public class BookDaoImpl implements BookDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED,rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    @Override
    public boolean addBook(Book book) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
          TransactionStatus status=null;
          try {
             status = TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus();
          } catch (NoTransactionException e) {
              System.err.println(e);
          }
          System.out.println("from addBook: "+status!=null? "active transaction": "no transaction");

        
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
//      Transaction trans = session.beginTransaction();
        
//      try {
            session.save(book);
//          trans.commit();
            return true;
//      }
//      catch(Exception e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//          trans.rollback();
//          return false;
//      }
//      finally {
//      session.close();
//      }
        
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Book> getBookList(int limit, int offset) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
        int finalLimit = limit!=0?limit:10;
        int finalOffset = offset!=0?offset:0;
                
        return (List<Book>) sessionFactory.openSession().createCriteria(Book.class)
//              .createAlias("Book.id", "BookId")
                .addOrder(Order.desc("id"))
                .setFirstResult(finalOffset)
                .setMaxResults(finalLimit)
                .list();
    }

    @Override
    public Book getBook(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        String hqlQuery = "from Book Where id=:id";
        return (Book) sessionFactory.openSession().createQuery(hqlQuery).setParameter("id", id).uniqueResult();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Book> getBook(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        String hqlQuery = "from Book Where title=:title";
        return (List<Book>) sessionFactory.openSession().createQuery(hqlQuery).setParameter("title", name).list();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Book> getBooks(String writer, String language, String category, int limit, int offset) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
        Book b = new Book();        
        b.setWriter(writer);
        b.setLanguage(language);
        b.setCategory(category);
        
        boolean flag =false;
        
        String hqlQuery = " from Book WHERE ";
        
        if(writer!=null && !writer.isEmpty()) {
            hqlQuery = hqlQuery + "writer=:writer ";
            flag=true;
        }
        
        if(language!=null && !language.isEmpty()) {
            hqlQuery = flag==true?  hqlQuery + "AND language=:language ":hqlQuery + "language=:language";
            flag=true;
        }

        if(category!=null && !category.isEmpty()) {
            hqlQuery = flag==true?  hqlQuery + "AND category=:category ":hqlQuery + "category=:category ";
            flag=true;
        }
        
        hqlQuery = hqlQuery + " Order By id desc";
        
        return (List<Book>) sessionFactory.openSession().createQuery(hqlQuery).setProperties(b)
                .setFirstResult(offset)
                .setMaxResults(limit)
                .list();
        
    }

}
```

Below is StoreDaoImpl code

```
package com.freetests4u.dao.impl;

import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.NoTransactionException;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus;
import org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.freetests4u.dao.StoreDao;
import com.freetests4u.dto.StoreAction;
import com.freetests4u.model.Store;

@Component
public class StoreDaoImpl implements StoreDao{

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    
    @Override
    public void updateStore(int bookId, StoreAction action) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        
        try {
            String hql ="";
            if(action==StoreAction.INCREMENT) {
            hql = "UPDATE Store s SET s.count=s.count+1";
            }
            else if(action==StoreAction.DECREMENT){
                hql = "UPDATE Store s SET s.count=s.count-1";
            }
            
            int count = session.createQuery(hql).executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("updated count: "+count);
            
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Store getBookCountByBookId(int bookId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        
        try {
            String hql ="from Store where bookId=:bookId";
            
            return (Store) session.createQuery(hql)
                    .setParameter("bookId", bookId)
                    .uniqueResult();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        finally {
            session.close();
        }
        
    }
    
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED,rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    @Override
    public void createStoreEntry(int bookId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
//      Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
        
          TransactionStatus status=null;
          try {
             status = TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus();
          } catch (NoTransactionException e) {
              System.err.println(e);
          }
          System.out.println("from createStoreEntry: "+status!=null? "active transaction": "no transaction");

        
//      try {
            Store store = new Store();
            store.setBookId(bookId);
            store.setBookCount(0);
            store.setDeleted(false);
            session.save(store);
//          tr.commit();
//      }
//      catch(Exception e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//          throw e;
//      }
//      finally {
//          session.close();
//      }
    }
    
}
```

Below is BookServiceImpl code

```
package com.freetests4u.service.impl;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.NoTransactionException;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.freetests4u.dao.BookDao;
import com.freetests4u.dao.StoreDao;
import com.freetests4u.dto.BookSearchRequest;
import com.freetests4u.exceptions.DuplicateBookEntryException;
import com.freetests4u.model.Book;
import com.freetests4u.service.BookService;

@Service
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService{
    
    @Autowired
    BookDao bookDao;
    
    @Autowired
    StoreDao storeDao;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED,rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    @Override
    public void addBook(Book b) throws DuplicateBookEntryException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
//      List<Book> old = bookDao.getBook(b.getTitle().toLowerCase());
//      if(old.size()>0) {
//          throw new DuplicateBookEntryException("Book with same name already exists");
//      }       
        
//      Sessio  
        
          TransactionStatus status=null;
          try {
             status = TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus();
          } catch (NoTransactionException e) {
              System.err.println(e);
          }
          System.out.println(status!=null? "active transaction": "no transaction");

          try {
        storeDao.createStoreEntry(13);
        bookDao.addBook(b);
          }
          catch(Exception e) {
              System.out.println("throwing exception");
              e.printStackTrace();
              throw e;
          }
    }

    @Override
    public Book getBook(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return bookDao.getBook(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Book> getBooks(int limit, int offset) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        return bookDao.getBookList(limit, offset);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Book> getBook(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return bookDao.getBook(name);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Book> getBooks(BookSearchRequest br) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return bookDao.getBooks(br.getWriter(), br.getLanguage(), br.getCategory(), br.getLimit(), br.getOffset());
    }

}
```

It will be great if you can point out what's wrong in the above code. Thanks

Comment: Why do you inject a SessionFactory and open a new session each time? That seems very very suspicious to me. Normally you just inject the session and use it.

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer I'm now using SessionFactory.getCurrentSession() to obtain session from sessionFactory & this change solved the problem. Can you answer the question here, So that I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();` - this will create a brand new Session each time. Instead you simply want to inject the current Session and use that.

Btw., I'm not sure whether your Configuration is necessary. Usually Spring Boot Autoconfiguration takes care of everything if you include the right starter (for Spring Boot 2 that's spring-boot-starter-data-jpa).

```
@Component
public class BookDaoImpl implements BookDao {

    @Autowired
    private Session session; // Might want to use JPA EntityManager instead
    
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = MyException.class) // propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED is default anyway
    @Override
    public boolean Book addBook(Book book) {
        // No need to handle transaction manually
        session.save(book);
        return true; // Maybe return something more useful
    }
}
```